# Duda entre listas y tuplas de python

Tags: python

buenas tardes:

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, un completo novato, entonces quiero pedirles ayuda con respecto al siguiente código que no logro comprender:

```
txt = 'Pero qué luz se deja ver allí'
palabras = txt.split()
t = list()

for palabra in palabras:
    t.append((len(palabra), palabra))

t.sort(reverse=True)

res = list()

for longitud, palabra in t:
    res.append(palabra)

print(res)
```

Entiendo el funcionamiento del código, lo que no entiendo es la explicación del libro: "Python para todos" en el que dice lo siguiente:

> El primer bucle genera una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla es una
> palabra precedida por su longitud.

¿Dónde está la tupla, es que acaso se refiere a el elemento entre comas como por ejemplo 'Pero' en sí mismo una tupla o qué? Ya que solo veo elementos que operan con una lista y ¿los elementos de una tupla no se supone que se encierran entre paréntesis?

De antemano gracias a quien me pudiera aclarar esta duda. Y disculpas si la pregunta es demasiado simple o zonza, pero necesito aclararme esto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copiaré parte del código el cuál es el siguiente e imprimiré lo que se ha almacenado en t:

```
txt = 'Pero qué luz se deja ver allí'
palabras = txt.split()
t = list()

for palabra in palabras:
    t.append((len(palabra), palabra))

print(t)
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
[(4, 'Pero'), (3, 'qué'), (3, 'luz'), (2, 'se'), (4, 'deja'), (3, 'ver'), (4, 'allí')]
```

Aunque todo esté almacenado en conjunto en una lista, lo que hay dentro son tuplas. Sí, el bucle genera una lista de tuplas con dos elementos, el primero la longitud, el segundo la palabra. De allí a que hable de tuplas.

Ten en cuenta que en el append (la inserción) en la lista t:

```
t.append((len(palabra), palabra))
```

Es lo siguiente lo que se inserta:

```
(len(palabra), palabra)
```

Estás añadiendo (append) dentro de la lista (t) elementos que son tuplas ya que están entre paréntesis.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me aclaraste todo y no sé qué me pasó que no se me ocurrió revisar la lista 't'.

Comment: No te preocupes, para eso estamos. Es bueno siempre "debuggear" o depurar el código un poco para ver más o menos como va funcionando todo. Cualquier duda aquí estamos. Saludos.